# Program not recognizing multiple process

Tags: c#

I wrote a simple C# console application to write text to an notepad process. I took the pieces for writing to the process from **SO**, but I wanted to take this to the next step, make it a little more useful.

```
delegate void WriteText(Process[] notepads, bool WriteAll, int index);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);
    static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length != 0)
        {
            if (args != null)
            {
                string fullStr = "";
                foreach (string str in args)
                {
                    fullStr += str + " ";
                }
                int index = 0;
                WriteToNotepad(fullStr, ref index);
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Wrote ' {0} ' to notepad[ {1} ] !", fullStr, index));

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    static void WriteToNotepad(string text, ref int chosenNotepad)
    {
        WriteText write = (Process[] notepads, bool WriteAll, int index) =>
            {
                if (!WriteAll)
                {
                    if (notepads.Length == 0) return;
                    if (notepads[index] != null)
                    {
                        IntPtr child = FindWindowEx(notepads[index].MainWindowHandle, new IntPtr(0), "Edit", null);
                        SendMessage(child, 0x000c, 0, text);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int notepadIndex = 0; notepadIndex < notepads.Length; notepadIndex++)
                    {
                        IntPtr child = FindWindowEx(notepads[notepadIndex].MainWindowHandle, new IntPtr(0), "Edit", null);
                        SendMessage(child, 0x000c, 0, text);
                    }
                }
            };

        Process[] notes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");

        if (notes.Length < 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < notes.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", i, notes[i].Id));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nPick a number to select which notepad to edit.\nEnter 'ALL' to modify memory of every notepad process active:  ");
            string answer = Console.ReadLine();
            if (answer == "ALL")
            {
                write(notes, true, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    int ans = Convert.ToInt32(answer);
                    chosenNotepad = ans;
                    write(notes, false, Convert.ToInt32(ans));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n" + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**PROBLEM**: If you spectate the code, you'll see that I gather the **text** to write from `static void Main(params string[] args)`,  so I have arguments like this. [image: Debug settings]

It will write the text to the notepad correctly! :) Except it's not the way it should work...

If you take a look at the function `WriteToNotepad()` it will save all the processes with name **notepad** to the variable names `notes`.

I have 3 notepads wide open, which means `notes` **length** should be 3, and if it is, it will print all the notepad indexes & names, and the user can select which one to modify, if user inputs 'ALL' the program will modify every notepad process there is. The problem is, it straight modifies first notepad process there is. [image: cmd result]

I simply can't find the problem here, any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `if (notes.Length < 1)` makes the method return without doing anything, leaving `ref int chosenNotepad` to its default value, `0`, then printing a lie.

Change it to `if (notes.Any())`.

You can find this out by placing breakpoints and stepping through your code.

Comment: Oh, that seemed to work, thanks in advance! :) Why it does return like that? And I have 3 notepad processes so that should basically be true, I'm confused O.o

Comment: @TuukkaX debug the code step by step, and find a place where code is doing something different than you expect it to be doing in that place. Then tell us what place is it, what do you expect, and what does it actually happen, and then we may explain it to you better.

Comment: @TuukkaX read the first sentence. Your code only executes `if (notes.Length < 1)`, or "when **no** notepad is running". You want to invert that to `Length >= 1`, which is equivalent to `.Any()`.

Comment: @Dialecticus from now on, I'll go ahead and do that everytime since this was just an stupid little mistake from me that I didn't notice :D Thanks to CodeCaster for explaining the problem +1 :)